# making rdd from a text file that contains path to the actual file

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have to make rdd from a text file that contains path to the original text file. I have a directory which contains three files- **hw2-file.txt** , **hw2-file-10mb.txt**(the actual text file) and **hw2.ipynb** which is a jupyter notebook I have to work on. My **hw2-file.txt** contains

> /home/kriti/Downloads/local test/hw2-file-10mb.txt

Then I ran the following code-

```
with open('./hw2-files.txt') as f:
    file_path= [w.strip() for w in f.readlines() if w.strip()]
lines= sc.textFile(file_path)
lines.cache().count()
```

and got the following error-

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist: file:/home/kriti/Downloads/local test/file_path

Is there any other way to read the text file of this type into an RDD?

Comment: Are you using spark or only python? As per code, i think you are using only python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only text file from directory then you can use path with `*.txt` as suffix.

You can write your code as below in pySpark.

```
//Reading Path from file hw2-file.txt
    >>> pathlist = sc.textFile(<path of hw2-file.txt>).collect()

    //Cast RDD value into String like    
    // "/home/kriti/Downloads/local test/hw2-file-10mb.txt"
    >>> path = str("".join(pathlist)) 

  //data of hw2-file-10mb.txt file
    >>> rdd  = sc.textFile(path) 
    >>>rdd.count()
```

Comment: I think where I am getting wrong is - file path = ['/home/kriti/Downloads/local test/hw2-file-10mb.txt'] is a list of one element. I  want to convert file_path to type str... how can that be done?

Comment: I have done same think just convert list into string. check second step in my code. But just from learning perspective, the way you are writing code will not work in cluster mode. It is not good way to read file in pyspark. Concept of python and pyspark is different.